# The word 'Surviving' in 'one of the the earliest surviving poems'

Tags: gerunds, past-participles, present-participles

One of the earliest surviving Anglo Saxon poems, Widsith, is the autobiographical record of such a scop.

Here, Surviving is a Participle or a Gerund?

Can we say "Widsith is one of the earliest Survived Anglo Saxon" omitting conjunction and a helping verb( which have).

Widsith is one of the earliest Anglo Saxon poems which have survived.

Comment: No, we can't omit _which have_ (or _to have_).  To do so makes it look as though surviving was something done to the poems.

Comment: It means ,doing so would make it look like like a passive structure...

Comment: It's essentially a *metaphoric* extension of ***survive = remain alive*** into *remain **accessible to future generations***. Where the continuous participle is being used ***adjectivally*** to mean *one of the earliest Anglo Saxon poems **that are** [still] **accessible*** (we can still find the actual text, from "originals" ***or*** from later copies).